# How to add CRL distribution point

Tags: ejbca

After manually creating the Certificate profile ,lets say **foo**, I enrolled **create certificate using CSR**.
While configuring certificate profile, I checkmarked **CRL Distribution Points** parameter "use" under Certificate Revocation List Distribution

Under CRL Distribution Point URI, EJBCA provided default URL which I replaced it with http://localhost:8080/ejbca/publicweb/webdist/mycrl.crl

I left the CRL Issuer field unchanged. I want to know how do I generate crl in the above mentioned URL so that I can get access of it throught the following command, `wget -O mycrl.crl http://localhost:8080/ejbca/publicweb/webdist/mycrl.crl`

I have tried creating a new service under System Functions-> Services , configuring it with a particular periodic timer with "CRL Updater" as a service, but it did not changed the last update time of CRL.